# Recurring Payment With Authorize.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway, authorize.net, recurring-billing

I am trying to implement `Authorize.Net` in an `ASP.NET` web form app and as I am new to it, was going through its official website and few other random sites to learn about it. The following links helped me a bit:

[Recurring Bill](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#recurring-billing)

[Recurring Bill Code Sample](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-csharp/blob/master/RecurringBilling/CreateSubscription.cs)

So far, the following code snippet seems ok to implement as it has few configurations to set up and created a sandbox account to get it done:

```
 ApiOperationBase<ANetApiRequest, ANetApiResponse>.MerchantAuthentication = new merchantAuthenticationType()
 {
      name            = ApiLoginID,
      ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.transactionKey,
      Item            = ApiTransactionKey,
 };

 paymentScheduleTypeInterval interval = new paymentScheduleTypeInterval();

 interval.length = intervalLength;                        // months can be indicated between 1 and 12
 interval.unit   = ARBSubscriptionUnitEnum.days;

 paymentScheduleType schedule = new paymentScheduleType
 {
     interval            = interval,
     startDate           = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),      // start date should be tomorrow
     totalOccurrences    = 9999,                          // 999 indicates no end date
     trialOccurrences     = 3
 };

 #region Payment Information
 var creditCard = new creditCardType
 {
     cardNumber      = "4111111111111111",
     expirationDate  = "1028"
 };
```

I've a tricky requirement and one thing to confirm here. In the web app, if a user signs up in the website, then an amount of $1 will be charged with `Authorize.Net` api and if the user uses the website for more than three days after sign up, then it'll automatically redirect the user to a monthly subscription (So another fee will be charged here).

Is it something that can be handled with `Authorize.Net` and for recurring bill, do I require to save user credit card details in the website's database or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would want to do is:

1. Create a [customer payment profile](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles-create-customer-profile) (this allows you to collect their credit card information only once so you can use it again if you reach step 3)
2. [Using that payment profile, charge](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-charge-a-customer-profile) your initial $1.00 amount
3. If they do not cancel after three days, [using that payment profile, charge](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-charge-a-customer-profile) their first month's subscription payment. You do this as a "regular" transactions because subscriptions do *not* begin immediately.
4. [Create a subscription using their payment profile ID](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#recurring-billing-create-a-subscription-from-customer-profile) (so you do not have to store their credit card details yourself) with the start date set to 30 days out.

Be sure to store their profile ID and payment profile ID for later reference. You will need it to charge their first subscription payment and to create their subscription (you will need to trigger these from your website, most likely through an automated process). At some point you will also need to [update their credit card information](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles-update-customer-payment-profile) once it expires.

Comment: The references seem very helpful and thanks for it @John Conde. Though few things to clear here, to create customer payment profile, I've to do this during user registration in the website. So I get a customer profile id in response that I require to save in my end. Then for the charge after three days, I'll use that profile id. Now the question is how this subscription thing will be auto-converted, is this required to do something from the website (I believe, from website, it'll check somehow) using `Authorize.Net`?

Comment: I've updated my answer to add more clarity and also address the fact that subscriptions are not charged immediately.

Comment: Got it and already done a test for a regular subscription @John Conde. There should be a separate system to handle auto-conversion. Thanks for your time to update the post and really appreciate it. Last thing to clear, say the subscription charges a user and `Authorize.Net` will do it periodically (By month). How to notify the system or website that the recurring bill has been generated for the user, like again I need to check it from the website?

Comment: You can use [webhooks](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/webhooks.html) to be notified that a recurring payment has occurred and determine the status of it.

Comment: Could you check my updated post @John Conde? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: That's a whole new problem and should be a new question

Comment: Ok @John Conde, I was planning to finish it off in this thread. I'll create another one, so you can check around.

Comment: Created a new thread here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67466586/webhook-notification-with-authorize-net @John Conde. You can check and closing this one.